# getting log file issues and access denied when running spark on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark

Hi am trying to execute spark with was but I am getting the below issue when I run it on aws cluster.

```
log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file from URL [file:/etc/spark/conf/log4j.properties].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /etc/spark/conf/log4j.properties (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
```

and

```
17/09/28 19:50:16 INFO ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 15, (reason: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 9AA4363BB8D75166), S3 Extended Request ID: UzSFXBXoJgTar68arZIr6X68gKuIVLOmUub/u5gwnZ9QYC+QpqKZhr7M848mj0OdijyKXGYTJ3I=
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1286)
```

Comment: Does /etc/spark/conf/log4j.properties exist and can the process that's running spark read it?

Comment: It ideally looks into SPARK_HOME/conf/log4j.properties. Do check if you have your environment set correctly.

Comment: could you please let me know how to set those environment variables I am working on Scala in eclipse.